# SQLException Error in Java

Tags: java, sqlexception

Whenever i run this code this error follows like . . .!

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:982)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:927)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkRowPos(ResultSetImpl.java:841)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getStringInternal(ResultSetImpl.java:5650)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5570)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getDoubleInternal(ResultSetImpl.java:2463)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getDouble(ResultSetImpl.java:2424)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getDouble(ResultSetImpl.java:2442)
at Library.main(Library.java:157)
```

The following is the code from main that i run and caught this error. . .

```
    System.out.println("Registration number of member returning book: ");
        String number = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Book shelf number");
        double bookNumber = input.nextDouble();

        double shelfNo;
        String borrower;
        long timeBookTaken;
        long timeToReturnBook;

        if(borrow.hasBeenBorrowed(bookNumber))
        {
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM borrowed WHERE shelfNumber = '"+ bookNumber +"'";
            ResultSet rs = con.readDatabase(sql,statement);



                //Statement statmnt = con.getStatement();
                shelfNo = rs.getDouble("shelfNumber");
                borrower = rs.getString("borrowerRegNum");
                timeBookTaken = rs.getLong("timetaken");
                timeToReturnBook = rs.getLong("time_to_return");

                System.out.println(shelfNo+"\t"+borrower+"\t"+timeBookTaken+"\t"+timeToReturnBook);
```

The con(is an instance of DBConnection class). . .
readDatabase method is inside DBConnection class.

```
DBConnection class
===================


     package database;

    import java.sql.*;

    public class DBConnection
    {

        private static Connection connection;
        private static Statement statement;
        private static ResultSet resultset;

private static String mysqlURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/library";
private static String mysqlUsername = "root";
private static String mysqlPassword = "";

public DBConnection()
{
    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        connection
                 =   DriverManager.getConnection(mysqlURL,mysqlUsername,mysqlPassword);
        statement = connection.createStatement();

    }
    catch(Exception exception)
    {
        System.out.println("Error: "+ exception.getMessage());
    }

}

public Connection getConnection()
{
    return connection;
}


public Statement getStatement()
{
    return statement;
}

public ResultSet readDatabase(String sql,Statement statement) throws SQLException
{
    resultset = statement.executeQuery(sql);

    return resultset;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't called [`next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next%28%29) on the result set yet.  Not only does that tell you *if* there's another row in the result set, it advances the result set cursor to that row.

Enclose your "get" calls to the result set in

```
while (rs.next()) {

    // get calls here

}
```

so you process all rows, advancing to each row each loop.

Comment: @Yunus Einsteinium,If this solution worked for you,you should mark as accepted